Calculate/estimate power of existing central heating radiator (UK)?
Having one type of the radiator, how to "guess" it's output power to make sure I replace with comparable power output (little narrower, probably a bit higher)? Are there any on-line tools or any wisdom to apply in this case?

Make sure it has the same, or more, surface area. So, remember that some have flutes or fins to increase area etc ie single water channel no fins, single water channel with fins, double water channel etc etc

is this a: steam, hot water, or electric-resistance radiator?

It's hot water.

How much area are you expecting to heat with this radiator? Buy one rated to heat that size and ignore the capacity of the current one.

The current one is 1800 x 600 flat with convector. Calculated BTU for this room is 8201 (2.4kW) what puts dual side radiators with horizontal bars at practically the same size (±5 cm width). Now I can't find one matching my pipe centres (1835 mm).
